# Spark SQL query error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe "dailyshow"
Schema is:

```
scala> dailyshow.printSchema
root
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- occupation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- showdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- guest: string (nullable = true)
```

Sample Data is:

```
scala> dailyshow.show(5)
+----+------------------+---------+------+----------------+
|year|        occupation| showdate| group|           guest|
+----+------------------+---------+------+----------------+
|1999|             actor|1/11/1999|Acting|  Michael J. Fox|
|1999|          Comedian|1/12/1999|Comedy| Sandra Bernhard|
|1999|television actress|1/13/1999|Acting|   Tracey Ullman|
|1999|      film actress|1/14/1999|Acting|Gillian Anderson|
|1999|             actor|1/18/1999|Acting|David Alan Grier|
+----+------------------+---------+------+----------------+
```

Below code is used to transform and generate results which return the top 5 occupations between the time period "01/11/1999" and "06/11/1999"

```
 sqlContext.sql("select occupation, count(*) as count from dailyshow 
 where to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(showdate,'MM/dd/yyyy') as 'timestamp')) >= '1999-01-11' 
 and   to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(showdate,'MM/dd/yyyy') as 'timestamp'))  <= '1999-06-11' 
 group by occupation 
 order by count 
 desc limit 5
 ")
```

**Below is the error:**

```
NoViableAltException(307@[])
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.primitiveType(HiveParser.java:39374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.castExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:5434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.atomExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6716)


org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot recognize input near ''timestamp'' ')' ')' in primitive type specification; line 1 pos 112
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.createPlan(HiveQl.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.ExtendedHiveQlParser$$anonfun$hiveQl$1.apply(ExtendedHiveQlParser.scala:41)
```

Kindly help..

Comment: You can follow this doc of SPARK SQL : [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) I hope that help you

Comment: what is the question? you already showed a solution using spark sql (DataFrame API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're asking for the Hive style SparkSQL solution:

```
val dailyshow = Seq(
  ("1999", "actor", "1/11/1999", "Acting", "Michael J. Fox"),
  ("1999", "Comedian", "1/12/1999", "Comedy", "Sandra Bernhard"),
  ("1999", "television actress", "1/13/1999", "Acting", "Tracey Ullman"),
  ("1999", "film actress", "1/14/1999", "Acting", "Gillian Anderson"),
  ("1999", "actor", "1/18/1999", "Acting", "David Alan Grier")
).toDF(
  "year", "occupation", "showdate", "group", "guest"
)

dailyshow.createOrReplaceTempView("dailyshowView")

val dailyshow2 = spark.sqlContext.sql("""
  SELECT occupation, count(*) as count FROM dailyshowView
  WHERE to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(showdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp)) >= '1999-01-11'
    AND to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(showdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp)) <= '1999-06-11'
  GROUP BY occupation
  LIMIT 5
""")

dailyshow2.show
+------------------+-----+
|        occupation|count|
+------------------+-----+
|      film actress|    1|
|             actor|    2|
|          Comedian|    1|
|television actress|    1|
+------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks..Its seems to be correct, but I am getting an **error..** `NoViableAltException(307@[])
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.primitiveType(HiveParser.java:39374)
`

Comment: I am _reframing_ the question giving additional details.

Comment: @Jayson, in your revised SparkSQL statement, `timestamp` within `unix_timestamp(showdate,'MM/dd/yyyy') as timestamp` is enclosed with quotes.  It shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked.. sorry.. was very silly from my end.

Comment: No problem.  Glad that it helps.